# How to fix different results on mobile when using html2pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2pdf

I'm working on a project and need automated shipping labels.
It works well on desktop:
[desktop example html2pdf.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAnER.png)

but on mobile i get this result:
[mobile example html2pdf.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HexVX.png)

Here's my code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Shipping Label</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.3/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>
        <style>
          @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
          body {
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
          }
          .adres {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            /*align-items: center;*/
            justify-content: center;
            padding-left: 100px;
            font-size: 70px;
            width: calc(100% - 100px);
            height: calc(100vh - 100px);
          }
          .postzegelcode {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            border: none;
            padding: 20px;
          }

          .logo {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            padding-left: 100px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 30px;
          }

          td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 45px;
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
            font-size: 40px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="adres">
          <span style="margin-bottom: 0px;"
            >NAME<br />STREET<br />PLACE<br />POSTALCODE</span
          >
        </div>
        <table class="postzegelcode" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>9</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="logo">
          domain.com
        </div>

        <script>
          const content = document.body.innerHTML;
          document.body.innerHTML = content; // Reset body to remove any existing content

          const options = {
            filename: "pdf_document.pdf",
            image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 2, windowWidth: 1024 },
            jsPDF: { format: "a4", orientation: "landscape" }
          };

          html2pdf()
            .set(options)
            .from(document.body)
            .toPdf()
            .get("pdf")
            .then((pdf) => {
              const blob = new Blob([pdf.output("blob")], {
            type: "application/pdf"
             });
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          window.location.href = url; // Open the PDF in the current tab
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried wrapping the content in a div and setting the div's height and width to the aspect ratio of A4 Landscape but that didn't seem to solve the problem and just caused more. This is the only functioning version I could share.

Comment: What result are you hoping for?

Comment: The same result as on dekstop on any device. So the end user doesn't have to be on a computer to get the PDF they need.

Comment: Try setting the width of your body to a fixed width; don't let it be responsive. Seems like a cool library.